# downloading blank pdf when using express to call looker api

Tags: node.js, rest, express, axios, looker

When calling `render_task_results(render_task_id)` looker API from my NodeJS based API using axios I am getting the binary data but when downloading it it is giving me blank PDF.

PFB my code.

```
const response = await createPdf(TaskID, lookerToken.access_token);
res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
res.status(200).send(response.body);
return res;


export async function createPdf(TaskID, lookerToken): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const url = "someurl/api/3.1/render_tasks/" + TaskID + '/results';
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': 'token ' + lookerToken
        };
        axios({
            headers,
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            responseType: 'blob'
        }).then((response: any) => {
            resolve({
                body: response.data
                //statusCode: response.status,
            });
        })


    });
}
```